# SimpleModal basic modal window displays invalid page on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am using SimpleModal Basic Modal Dialog and when I try to implement a modal window popup on change of a jump menu, the dialog box opens, but I am quickly redirected to a url that doesn't exist.

How do I prevent that from happening?

Here is my HTML for the jump menu:

```
<select name="fieldname" size="1" onChange="go()" class="select" >
              <option selected="selected"><em>Questions Bulk Edit Options...</em></option>
              <option value="http://74.39.250.15/questions_listing.asp?categoryState=1">Change Category Assignments</option>
              <option class="basicConfirmapprove" href="#">Change Status to Approved</option>
              <option value="http://74.39.250.15/questions_listing.asp?categoryState=2">Move to Another Folder</option>
            </select>
```

Here is my JavaScript for the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function go(){
location=
document.Category.fieldname.
options[document.Category.fieldname.selectedIndex].value
}
//-->
</script>
```

Here is my HTML for the modal window:

```
<div id="basic-modal-confirmapprove">
            <%  
'Page Preferences
PageName = ""
%>

<!--#include file="header_modal.asp"-->
<div><center>Are you sure you want to approve all the selected items?</center></div> 
  <br />
<div align="center"><a href="#" class="button simplemodal-close">Cancel</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="keybutton simplemodal-close">OK</a></div>
<!--#include file="footer_modal.asp"-->
```

And here is my JavaScript for the modal window:

```
// Load dialog on click
$('#basic-modal .basicConfirmapprove').click(function (event){
    $('#basic-modal-confirmapprove').modal();

    return false;
});
```

How do I prevent the jump to "....com/Change Status to Approved" url? Obviously it doesn't exist.  If I click back, it shows the previous window with the modal window perfectly.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the onchange="go()" event handler wired up, this code will execute as soon as the drop down value changes. You will need to put in something like this if you don't want to redirect:

```
var redirectValue =  document.Category.fieldname.options[document.Category.fieldname.selectedIndex].value;

if (redirectValue.substring(0,4) == "http")
{
    window.location = redirectValue;
}
```

This way the redirect will only happen if the value starts with "http", so if they choose the basicConfirmapprove then you should be safe

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank @Roysvork!  Worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad I could help! Just make sure you test what would happen if redirectValue was less than 4 chars long, I'm not sure if it would crash or not. Not an issue for you at the moment but best to check!